# asp.net ModalPopupExtender show's then hides problem

Tags: asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I have a simple ModalPopupExtender sample but can't seem to get it working properly.
I've followed the code from an online sample and it's similar to a lot of the other online examples but when I run it, the popup panel will quick show then then hides again.  I've set the targetcontrol to a linkbutton and when I click it it will show the popup, triggers a postback then hides it afterwards thus causing a quick flicker.

here is my code...

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Add Item</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:Panel ID="PanelPopup" runat="server" CssClass="ModalPopup" Width="500" Height="350" style="display:none;">
    <h1>test</h1>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" />
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:ModalPopupExtender 
    ID="ModalPopupExtender1" 
    runat="server" 
    BackgroundCssClass="Inactive"
    PopupControlID="PanelPopup"
    TargetControlID="LinkButton1"
    OkControlID="ButtonAdd"
    CancelControlID="ButtonCancel">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

I've also added Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" at the top

Can anyone see anything different or wrong about this please?
Many thanks!

Comment: very very strange, turns out this was due to using the v3.5 of the ajax toolkit.  When I changed the dll reference to point to v3 it works!  

Don't know what's going on there. I'm using visual studio 2008 and project was being built to .net 3.5 framework.  Anyone else had this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because your using the ASP ScriptManager. Try using the ToolkitScriptManager that comes with the AJAXControlToolkit.